# If $F:C\to D$ and $G:D\to E$ are functors, and both $GF$ and $G$ have a right adjoint, does $F$ has a right adjoint too?

Tags: category-theory

Suppose that $F:C\to D$ and $G:D\to E$ are functors such that both of $GF$ and $G$ have a right adjoint. Is it true that also $F$ has a right adjoint? And what if only $GF$ has a right adjoint?

Answer (score 4):

Let $E$ be a terminal category. Then a right adjoint of a functor $B\to E$ exists if, and only if, $B$ has a terminal object. So, to manufacture a counter example, all you need is to find two categories, $C,D$, and a functor $F:C\to D$, such that

- $C$ and $D$ have a terminal object
- $F$ has no right adjoint.

So, take $C=Grp$ and $D= Set$, and $F:C\to D$ to be the forgetful functor. There are of course many other examples, showing that in general adjunctions simply don't behave quite so nicely.

Answer (score 3):

The [counterexample](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/346468/5191) I previously gave can be adapted for this question as well. Take $\mathcal{C}$ to be the category of finite sets, $\mathcal{D}$ the category of all sets, and $\mathcal{E}$ to be the terminal category, with $F : \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{D}$ the inclusion and $G : \mathcal{D} \to \mathcal{E}$ the unique functor. Then both $G$ and $G F$ have right adjoints, sending the unique object of $\mathcal{E}$ to a terminal object $1$, but $F$ does not.

Comment: I should have noticed it by myself, thanks!