# $F:C\to D, G:D\to E$ are functors, $G$ has a right adj, $F$ is fully faithful, $G$ is faithful, $F$ is "relatively dense". Does $F$ have an adj?

Tags: category-theory

This is related to Questions [346458](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/346458/fc-to-d-gd-to-e-g-has-an-adjoint-f-is-fully-faithful-and-for-each) and [348459](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/348459/if-fc-to-d-and-gd-to-e-are-functors-and-both-gf-and-g-have-a-right-ad).

Suppose that $F:C\to D$ and $G:D\to E$ are functors such that $G$ has a right [left] adjoint $H$, $F$ is fully faithful, $G$ is faithful, and for each $Z\in E$ there exists $X \in C$ such that $F(X)=H(Z)$. Is it true that $F$ has a right or left adjoint? What if $GF$ has a right [left] adjoint? And what if both of $GF$ and $G$ have a right [left] adjoint?

Comment: What is the motivation behind these questions? Is there some concrete problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 1):

This calls for a counterexample of a different nature. Let $\mathcal{D}$ be the category of the finite subsets of an infinite set $X$ and their inclusions, let $\mathcal{C}$ be the full subcategory of the finite and cofinite subsets of $X$, and let $F : \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{D}$ be the inclusion. Let $\mathcal{E}$ be the trivial category and let $G : \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{E}$ be the unique functor. This is a faithful functor because there is at most one morphism between any two objects in $\mathcal{D}$. (Note that faithful functors do not have to be injective on objects!) Now, $G$ has both a left adjoint and a right adjoint, as does $G F$, and $F$ satisfies the condition you give, but $F$ admits neither a left adjoint nor a right adjoint, because it fails to preserve some limits and some colimits.